# How to use GoHighLevel API

Tags: automation, integration, access-token, high-level

Apologize first for my bad english and disorganized description.
However it is difficult to describe it more organized.

I am trying to use the API of GoHighLevel.
To use them, it requires to get access token.
And getting access token involves a complicated process and challenging to be automated.
It uses Oauth flow and I can't write code to get access token.

And also once access token is generated, it is expired after 24 day.

And what I need is to run the API on a cron job, say, daily.

And due to access token, I am not sure how I can implement this.

Please help me

I used selenium also to get access token but I think it is not an option.